# Linq query to find super set with checks

Tags: c#, linq

I want to query a list with some repetitive text, and with/without id value.

I have two condition to match,

1. any 2 same **[text, type]** group with ID is selected, else select the unique one.
2. any 2 texts, where one contains the other, the super set text is selected. [Singing, Dancing Singing => Dancing Singing]

> ```
> Type      Text            Id
>
> Name      John  
> Name      John            22
> Name      John Smith      2548
> Hobby     Singing         
> Hobby     Dancing Singing
> School    XYZ             
> School    XYZ             242
> ```

Output expected:

> ```
> Type      Text            Id
>
> Name      John Smith      2548
> Hobby     Dancing Singing
> School    XYZ             242
> ```

Comment: John, ID = 22 is unique.  So is John Smith ID = 2548.  Why should one over the other be selected?

Comment: because John smith contains John

Comment: The superset requirement makes this more complicated. In my opinion, it is also extremely vague and arbitrary. For example, how are you going to tell whether a "John" belongs to "John Smith" or "John Wayne"?

Comment: @Abion47 For 2 strings like "coronary artery disease" and "artery disease", I need to pull "coronary artery disease". 

"left artery disease" this could be another unique combination.

Comment: @ADeveloper You're missing the point. What if you have two unique combinations, and then later you run into a subset combination that could fit into either superset? If you had "John Smith" and "John Wayne" and then got another "John", which superset would you update? Both? Neither? And what would that mean for the earlier Johns that were merged into John Smith long before your algorithm knew of the existence of John Wayne? There is a slew of potential problems that would stem from treating a data set in this way, so I hope this exercise is for school or practice and not for production code.

Comment: @Abion47 thanks for the inputs. Currently its only selection of items based on logic. There is no merge of information.

Comment: @ADeveloper Not true. In your example, all the information from the previous Johns is merged into "John Smith". The ID value of the second John (22) is lost entirely from the end result. You are merging data, and in the process, you are discarding information. And this policy is fine if that's what you want, but it begs the question as to what the algorithm should do when it's ambiguous which of two supersets a data entry should be merged into.

Comment: @Abion47 is correct.  If you are using this for a real world application please rethink your design.  The answer I gave works with the limited data you provided.  It is not hard to think of datasets that will break this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ugly but it works:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        List<Record> records = BuildTestData();
        List<Record> deduped = DeDupe(records);
        Console.Clear();

        foreach (Record r in deduped)
            Console.WriteLine($"Type:{r.Typ}, Text:{r.Txt}, ID:{r.ID} ");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    static List<Record> DeDupe(List<Record> dupes)
    {
        List<Record> excludes = new List<Record>();
        excludes.AddRange(dupes.GroupBy(x => new { x.Typ, x.Txt }).Where(y => y.Count() > 1).SelectMany(z => z.Where(a => string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.ID))));
        excludes.AddRange(dupes.Where(x => !excludes.Any(y => x == y) && dupes.Any(z => x != z && x.Txt != z.Txt && z.Txt.Contains(x.Txt))));
        return dupes.Where(x => !excludes.Any(y => x == y)).ToList();
    }


    static List<Record> BuildTestData()
    {
        return new List<Record>
        {
            new Record { Typ = "Name", Txt = "John", ID = null},
            new Record { Typ = "Name", Txt = "John", ID = "22"},
            new Record { Typ = "Name", Txt = "John Smith", ID = "2548"},
            new Record { Typ = "Hobby", Txt = "Singing", ID = null},
            new Record { Typ = "Hobby", Txt = "Dancing Singing", ID = null},
            new Record { Typ = "School", Txt = "XYZ", ID = null},
            new Record { Typ = "School", Txt = "XYZ", ID = "242"},
        };
    }
}

public class Record
{ 
    public string Typ { get; set; }
    public string Txt { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm still curious how this would handle a "John Wayne" added after the "John Smith", followed by another record that was again just "John".

Comment: OP would be best one to tell you.  My guess this is a homework problem... your questions are too real world.

Comment: I despise homework questions like this. They train you to make awful assumptions about your potential dataset.

Comment: @Sam thanks for the answer, this helps in shaping up the query